# PHP Get file name starting with prefix

Tags: php

This is a custom function. At the moment, this function get all the file in the default directory, strip ".php" and list them.

The problem is that I want to only get files from the directory which has starting prefix "tpl-" Example : tpl-login-page.php

```
/* Get template name of the file */
        function get_template_name (){
            $files = preg_grep('~\.(php)$~', scandir(admin . "templates/default/"));
                foreach($files as $file){
                    $file = str_replace('.php','',$file);
                    echo $file . "<br/>";
                }
        }
```

Comment: So you're probably looking to modify the preg_grep expression `~\.(php)$~`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to change the regular expression in preg_grep:

```
$files = preg_grep('~^tpl-.*\.php$~', scandir(admin . "templates/default/"));
```

Explanation:

1. `^tpl-` - starting with "tpl-"
2. `.*` - any characters
3. `\.php$` - ending with ".php"

Answer (score 24):

I like another, simple way:

**1. get all files in folder**

```
   $path = './images'; 
   $files = glob($path.'/*');
```

**2. get all files having extension .jpg**

```
   $path = './images'; 
   $files = glob($path.'/*.jpg');
```

**3. get all files having prefix myprefix_**

```
   $path = './images'; 
   $files = glob($path.'/myprefix_*');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $target_file_png = glob($target_dir.'/group_'.$groupId.'*.png');
```

`$target_file_png`  will return an array containing all the files in folder specified in the path `$target_dir` starting with `'/group_'.$groupId.'` and specify the file format as `*.png`